# How-to edit EDMX programmatically

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using a database-first process.  I've got hundreds of tables imported into my EDMX and generated CUD procs imported as well.  The generated CUD procs use a naming convention based on the table name and he CUD operation.

How can I write some code to open the EDMX, associate the CUD procs with the proper entities, and save the EDMX?

This is a lazy-developer, design-time task - this will not be happening at runtime.

Comment: The EDMX is just an XML. You can use whatever XML libraries you like to manipulate it.

Comment: Have you opened the file with a text editor yet, its just a simple XML file. I don't understand what you are having trouble doing, parsing through the XML?

Comment: I understand that it's XML.  Is there a .Net library (System.Data.Entity.Design, maybe?) that already supports adding EntityTypeMapping/ModificationFunctionMapping to the EntitySetMapping collection, and then saving the file?

Comment: The Entities are partial classes so you can just create another partial and add whatever properties and methods you want.

Comment: I don't want to modify the Entities.  I want to modify the EDMX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I wanted was a free library which contained the object-model representation of the EDMX.  This would allow developers to edmx.Load(pathToEdmx), query the object-model, make changes, and edmx.Save().  Apparently, such a library doesn't exist.

So, I wrote some code to load the XML, query the XML, make some changes, and save.  Not as rich as an object-model with validation and helpful exceptions (and very prone to typos), but it worked.

Comment: I ran into same problem, if you could share your code that'd be great. Thank you.